# Trying to Create my Very First User Defined Function

Tags: r

I've been using R for a while now, just for simple things.  Now, I'm trying to create a function to calculate the Black-Scholes value of an asset.  This is a pretty standard thing in the finance sector.  I'm pretty sure the syntax is right, but I'm getting a weird result.

Here are my parameters:

```
myfunction(1000000000,500000000,.04,.2,5)
```

Here is my function:

```
myfunction <- function(Firm_Value, Face_Value, Rate, Volatility_Value, Time)
{
s <- Firm_Value
X <- Face_Value
r <- Rate
v <- Volatility_Value
T <- Time
t1 <- log(s / X) + (r + v ^ 2 / 2) * T
t2 <- v * sqrt(T)
d1 <- t1 / t2
t3 <- log(s / X) + (r - v ^ 2 / 2) * T
d2 <- t3 / t2
ta <- s * qnorm(d1)
tb <- X * exp( - r * T) * qnorm(d2)
Equityvalue <- ta - tb
}
```

Here is my result:

```
Warning messages:
1: In qnorm(d1) : NaNs produced
2: In qnorm(d2) : NaNs produced
```

The result should actually be:

```
$593,035,186.31
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: debug(myfunction) will help you debug

Comment: From documentation : qnorm(p, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
with p being:  a vector of probabilities.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the `qnorm` function wants a probability. If you go through the individual calculations in the function, d1 and d2 do not give a probability. I'm thinking they give a quantile instead. I think you want `pnorm` instead of `qnorm`.

```
myfunction <- function(Firm_Value, Face_Value, Rate, Volatility_Value, Time)
{
s <- Firm_Value
X <- Face_Value
r <- Rate
v <- Volatility_Value
T <- Time
t1 <- log(s / X) + (r + v ^ 2 / 2) * T
t2 <- v * sqrt(T)
d1 <- t1 / t2
t3 <- log(s / X) + (r - v ^ 2 / 2) * T
d2 <- t3 / t2
ta <- s * pnorm(d1)
tb <- X * exp( - r * T) * pnorm(d2)
Equityvalue <- ta - tb
Equityvalue
}
```

Note: I also returned the final calculation by adding `Equityvalue` at the end. Your function above would not have printed the final result when calling the function.

Comment: Note as @brandon-lebeau wrote, what you want the function to return has to be executed on the last line, i.e. `Equityvalue` on the last line. you can also do this explicitly with `return(Equityvalue)`.

Comment: Yeap, that was it.  Thanks Brandon!